# .js file loading but not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

ok so here's my problem. I got an image slider from a tutorial on youtube, I had to change it around a bit since I'm working with angular and getting the images from an array. Everything loads if I check the sources in google chrome, my slider.js file is there, my css, etc... but the slider won't work, well it doesn't get activated is a better way to put it: if I insert the code from slider.js into the chrome console: hit enter -> BOOOM works perfectly, I've been looking for what the problem might be, tried adding the type="text/javascript" in the script tags, added the (document).ready in my jquery, still nothing... I'll add some of my code and hopefully anyone here can spot the problem!

**The slider.js File**

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

//settings for slider
var width = 320;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 3000;
var currentSlide = 1;

//cache DOM elements
var $slider = $('.project-slider');
var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

var interval;

function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {

            if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
}
function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$slideContainer
    .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
    .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();


});
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
  </head>

Comment: If this is in Angular, I would post your relevant controller / directive code. If I were a betting man, your Angular View gets loaded after your slider script has already fired. Probably dropping this code inside your controller (or in a service, called from the controller) would make it work.

Comment: You are a genius, Such a simple solution! Works like a charm, just copied the code into the directive controller... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive("projectGallery", function(){
    return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: "directives/project-gallery.html",
                controller: function(){
                                        this.current = 0;
                                        this.setCurrent = function(val){
                                            this.current = 0;
                                            if(val)
                                                this.current = val;
                                            };
                                        'use strict';

                                        $(document).ready(function() {

                                            //settings for slider
                                            var width = 320;
                                            var animationSpeed = 1000;
                                            var pause = 3000;
                                            var currentSlide = 1;

                                            //cache DOM elements
                                            var $slider = $('.project-slider');
                                            var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
                                            var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

                                            var interval;

                                            function startSlider() {
                                                interval = setInterval(function() {
                                                    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {

                                                        if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                                                            currentSlide = 1;
                                                            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }, pause);
                                            }
                                            function pauseSlider() {
                                                clearInterval(interval);
                                            }

                                            $slideContainer
                                                .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
                                                .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

                                            startSlider();


                                        });
                                       },
                controllerAs: 'gallery',
           };
});
```